# Oracle SQL : get distinct column values from table 1, get counts per value from table 2

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

Assuming table 1 has column called "class". Query to get all distinct values of "class" :

::select distinct class from table1

Now there is table 2, which has 3 rows with class "a", 2 rows with class "b" and 5 rows with class "c".

What should be the nested query that can query table 1, get all distinct values of "class" column, that is {a,b,c} in this example. And get counts from table2 for each distinct class in table1. output should look something like this :

---

class count

a 3

b 2

c 5

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT
    Table1.Class,
    COUNT(Table2.Class)
FROM
    Table1
    LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Class = Table2.Class
GROUP BY
    Table1.Class
```